# Error Service 'LogService.LogService' has zero application (non-infrastructure) endpoints

Tags: asp.net, wcf

I have a asp.net aspx web application projects where i have LogService.svc file which I believed is wcf service file.
When i run the application in Local IIS 'http://localhost/LogService/LogService.svc' it does not show error message while 
when i publish the same project in the Test Server. It shows error 'Service 'LogService.LogService' has zero application (non-infrastructure) endpoints. '

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Service ‘Namespace.ServiceName’ has zero application (non-infrastructure) endpoints. This might be because no configuration file was found for your application, or because no service element matching the service name could be found in the configuration file, or because no endpoints were defined in the service element.
  [And for get more information please visite :](https://www.pmichaels.net/2014/11/19/service-has-zero-application-non-infrastructure-endpoints/)

Comment: In local IIS (dev) it works fine. But when I published to test server, same configuration throwing the above error. Wouldn't it be throwing error in local as well if the namespace hadn't been correct.